# Rails asset_path and Angular Directive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to use asset_path to load an image in an Angular directive.

I use the .erb extension on the directive js file so I have access to the asset_path rails helper.

It works as long as I hardcode the image value like so:

```
template: '<img src="<%= asset_path("home.jpg") %>">'
```

However, if I try to use a scope variable instead of home.jpg, the asset_path references localhost/home.jpg instead of localhost/assets/home.jpg

I noticed that the following also does not work:

```
template: '<img src="<%= asset_path("'+ 'home.jpg' +'") %>">'
```

Is there any way around this? I basically want to be able to set an image when I call my directive in the HTML, and then have that passed into the directive js.erb file to output the image.

html:

```
<banner image="home.jpg"></banner>
```

directive.js.erb:

```
scope: {image: '@'},
template: '<img src="<%=asset_path("{{image}}")%>">
```

thanks!